# mod_proxy with ProxyRemote absolute URL - preserve relative URL

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

```
ProxyPass / https://example.com/
ProxyRemote https://example.com/ http://proxy:8080
```

The setup works through the proxy, but using mod_firehose I see mod_proxy modifying the url to include the full host name.
So instead of

```
GET /something HTTP/1.1
```

example.com sees:

```
GET https://examples.com/something HTTP/1.1
```

Is there any way to avoid this and keep the relative URL?